# Reversed series on bar chart with data loaded from table

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am currently testing Highcharts, as I have been considering using it in one of my projects. I have come across the following problem: when displaying bar chart with data loaded from html table, I see the series order is wrong (reversed). See the example here:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/scfd8Len/
```

What I want is the same series order as in the table ('Apples' first and 'Oranges' last). I was trying to use series.update() function, something like this:

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
for(var i=0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
    chart.series[i].update({ index: chart.series.length-1-i})
}
```

But it seems update() function reorders series array after each call, so you can't control it with such a loop. Is there any easy way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jamx78h/1/)

```
  data: {
            table: 'datatable',
            switchRowsAndColumns: true,
            parsed:function(columns){
                 columns.reverse();
                 columns.unshift(columns.pop());
            }
  },
  legend: {
            reversed:true
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.